# How to execute a python wheel developed using Poetry?

Tags: python, python-poetry, pipx

I have a poetry application and in poetry, one can set any python version in pyproject.toml. Once a wheel is built using poetry, I would like to share this to our users.Then, my users can execute this wheel similar to how they execute an exe in windows.

I checked pyinstaller but it generates a bulky exe.

I could see `pipx` has a command to run any wheel by creating a tmp environment using below command,

```
pipx run --spec C:\dev\poetry-demo\dist\poetry_demo-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl start
```

However, this throws an error when the python version used in Poetry (pyproject.toml) is different from the python version the pipx was installed.

Is there any alternative solution?

Comment: Can you add the error message to your question? And add your pyproject.toml file

Comment: "Once a wheel is built using poetry, I would like to share this to our users.Then, my users can execute this wheel similar to how they execute an exe in windows."—that's not how it works. You can create a bundled executable (e.g. using PyInstaller or PyOxidize) that will include a Python binary of your choice, but wheels don't do that. They need a Python binary from somewhere else.